# Output entry category in ExpressionEngine

Tags: expressionengine

I'm trying to output the category of a channel entry in ExpressionEngine, so that I can use it as a CSS class on an HTML element — see my attempted usage of `{category_name}` in the example below:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="panels"
    disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks|categories|category_fields" 
    status="open"
    dynamic="no"
}

    <div class="panel {category_name}">
        <h4>{title}</h4>
        {if panel_image}
            <img src="{panel_image}" /> 
        {/if}       
        <p>{panel_text}</p>
        <a href="{panel_link}">{panel_link_text}</a>
    </div>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use the entry's category as a CSS styling 'hook' ... but I can't figure out how to output an entry's category in my template.

I'd prefer to avoid using PHP in my template. Does anyone know how to improve my code?

Comment: Be sure to remove `categories|category_fields` from your `disable=` parameter, so ExpressionEngine can output category data.

Answer (score 7):

Wrap a [Categories Tag Pair](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories-tag-pair-parameters) around your `{category_name}`, which will output *all of the categories* assigned to an entry:

```
<div class="panel {categories}{category_name} {/categories}">
```

However, this will output the "pretty name" of your categories — which is undesirable for CSS classes or IDs on HTML elements:

```
<div class="panel Category One Category Two ">
```

Instead, use `{category_url_title}`, which is a *web safe version* of a Category Name:

```
<!-- Categories Tag Pair code -->
<div class="panel {categories}{category_url_title} {/categories}">

<!-- Outputs the following -->
<div class="panel category_one category_two ">
```

Pay special attention to the extra space in the above examples, which is needed to separate multiple categories (CSS Classes) with a space.

If you're obsessive compulsive about your markup, you can use the `backspace=` parameter to remove the trailing space when multiple categories are output:

```
{categories backspace="1"}{category_url_title} {/categories}
```

Should you wish to limit how many categories are output, or from which category group, use the [Categories Tag Pair Parameters](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories-tag-pair-parameters) to suit your needs:

```
<!-- No whitespace is needed, since we're outputting only one category -->
{categories limit="1"}{category_url_title}{/categories}
```

Here's the entire code snippet for review:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="panels" dynamic="no"}
    <div class="panel {categories}{category_url_title} {/categories}">
        <h4>{title}</h4>

        {if panel_image}
            <img src="{panel_image}" /> 
        {/if}

        <p>{panel_text}</p>
        <a href="{panel_link}">{panel_link_text}</a>
    </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```